# Bootstrap help in clarifying responsiveness for media devices

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am developing a website that needs to be able to respond to all device widths. I would like to gather some answers on a few questions I have.

- When defining the container, headings, columns, divs, selects, buttons and input fields, is it unnecessary to give any of them fixed widths in a custom css to override bootstrap?
- If fixed widths are defined in the custom css for any of these elements, are these suppose to be defined only within media queries themselves to ensure that all elements remain responsive?
- When and why would it be necessary to define fixed widths in a custom css to override bootstrap settings?
- I have defined some fixed widths for some of my select dropdowns, because they do not stretch to the width of their columns imposed by bootstrap, do you know why this is? Is there some css properties that I can do to ensure they fill the width of their column and also remain responsive?

Thank you.

Comment: This question is either too broad, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow. If you have a specific, answerable, programming issue, please provide full details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask